# "Will never write" vs "Would never write" vs "Never write"

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

What are the differences in meanings and usage in  the following sentences?

> 1. I **would never write** "america". Because it's wrong.
> 2. I **will never write** "america". Because it's wrong.
> 3. I **never write** "america". Because It's wrong.

In my opinion:

No 1. means I would never write 'america' in any circumstances whether in the present or in the future because I know it's wrong. (More emphatic)

No2. means I will never write 'america' in the future because I have known that it's wrong. (Only emphasizes future)

No3. means I never write 'america', it's just a fact that I don't write 'america' (only emphasizes the present)

Am I correct here in the interpretation of these sentences? What are the differences in meanings and usage in these sentences?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your explanations are all correct. I would only add that No. 2 carries a nuance that you just learned 'america' is wrong or that you've been writing 'america' incorrectly in the past (This is probably because  I cannot imagine another situation where such a sentence would be said).